# Fast method to check for substrings

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm currently programming a chat system based on a server - client model and using TCP as the communication protocol. Although it's working as expected, I'd like to further optimize important parts on the server side.

The server uses four extra threads to handle new connections, console input, etc, without blocking normal chat conversations. Well, there is only one thread for all messages that are being sent from client to client, so I assume it would be good to optimize the code there, as it would be the most obvious bottleneck. After reading the data on each client's socket, the data has to be processed using different steps. One of those steps would be to check for blocked words. And that's where my original question starts.

---

I played with `std::string::find()` and the `strstr()` function. According to my tests, `std::string::find()` was clearly faster than the old C-style `strstr()` function.

I know that the `std::string` is very well optimized, but C-style `char` arrays and their own functions always seemed to be somewhat faster, especially if the string has to be constructed over and over again.

So, is there anything faster than `std::string::find()` to scan a series of characters for blocked words? Is `std::string::find()` faster than `strstr()`, or are my benchmarks lousy? I know that the gain may be negligigle compared to effort needed to keep C-style `char` arrays and their functions clean, but I'd like to keep it as fast as possible, even if it is just for testing purposes.

---

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot to mention that I am using MSVC++2010 Express. I am only targeting Windows machines.

Comment: I'd be highly surprised if the substring search cost isn't dwarfed by your various I/O costs rendering this completely moot.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: Haha, thanks for that link, but I think you misunderstood. It was never my intention to create something like a swear-filter, as it would be completely useless and producing more problems than actual gain. Furthermore, I am only using this chat system locally, any further additions like this blocking system are only "implemented" for the sake of learning and experimenting. And sorry if the question has no real world gain and is just plain theoretical, but I was curious.

Answer (score 4):

Have you benchmarked to verify that lots of time is in fact being taken in the check for blocked words? My completely naive guess is you're gonna be spending lots more time waiting for RPCs than any local processing...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I wasn't able to test it, but I was just trying to optimize every function as good as I could. I agree that the time spent looking for blocked words would be rather low, but enhancing this particular function was part of my interest at the moment.

Comment: That's cool! If you're doing this to learn, then optimizing your string searching is probably a great thing. I found this but have never used it; might be fun to implement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: Wow, I've just read the first few parts and it seems to be very interesting! Thank you very much for this suggestion, I think I'll try to implement part of it myself, even if it'll be probably worse than the standard search, because this stuff looks quite sophisticated to me and I'm not sure I'll be able to implement it optimally :P

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the regular expressions library in either C++11 if you use that, or Boost if you don't? I'm not sure about the speed, but I believe they perform quite well. Additionally, if you are using this as a form of profanity filter, you'd want regular expressions anyway to prevent trivial circumvention.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I think I'll take a closer look at the boost library, although I probably won't be using it within this project. Boost seems to be very well developed anyway and I wanted to try it a long time ago. So, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There exist faster searching-algorithms than the linear search typically used in STL, or strstr.

[Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) is quite popular. It requires preprocessing of the target-string, which should be feasible for your usecase.

[Exact string matching algorithms](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/) is a free e-book with an in-depth description of different search-algorithms and their tradeofs.

Implementing more advanced algorithms could take considerable effort.
As said in the other answers, It is doubtful that string-searching is a bottle-neck in your chat-server.

Comment: As always, profile.  I was surprised to see that MSVC's string::find doesn't do the Boyer-Moore, until I realized for short strings it would be quite a bit slower.

Comment: It might be faster here, since the target-strings could be a bit longer, and preprocessing has to be done only once in total.

Comment: Thanks for these two links, I'm certainly gonna have a look at these! User "Moishe" already mentioned Boyer-Moore and I've only read the first few parts as I'm focusing on some other stuff too (analyzing the Diffie-Hellmann system takes some time, hehe). And I'm sure this e-book is going to be interesting to read too, thanks for that. And regarding the bottleneck, hmm, well, at the moment this is the only real check made by the server (the other being checking for the length of the input). I'm not entirely sure how this string search can be used yet, but I'm thinking of a limitation of '\n's.

Comment: If all you want to do is counting the '\n's in the input, than std::count_if in <algorithm> or something similar would be the fastest possible. (You can skip all algorithms above).